# Get only integer value from a string which contains bracket { in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a simple, very simple regex pattern like:

```
private static string FORMAT_REGEX = @"\{(\d)\}";
```

I have a string like `I have {323} dollars` and I want to get only `323`

When I used:

```
        Regex regex = new Regex(FORMAT_REGEX);
        Match match = regex.Match(format);

        if (match.Success)
        {
            return match.Groups[0].Value;  // here comes {323} instead of 323
        }
```

I'm sure that my pattern is wrong. What is the correct pattern ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a small mistake.

You need a + sign after `\d` like this: `\d+` to capture all digits.

And you need to get the first group: `match.Groups[1].Value`

Edit:

Here is a [.NETFiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/ap9jKE)

Answer (score 1):

`Groups[0]` will always return the whole capture. You need to get the value of `Groups[1]`.

Also, you need to capture multiple digits:

```
@"\{(\d+)\}";
// not
@"\{(\d)\}";
```

See the example at [MSDN: Match.Groups Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for an example of just this, where you can capture multiple groups as well as the whole string. In that example they use `\d{n}` to capture exactly `n` digits.